# Mock module export function with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a file `lib.ts`:

```
export const getValue() { return 'original value'; }

export const callGetValue() { return getValue(); }
```

And a test file `lib.spec.ts`:

```
import * as lib from './lib';

// ...
    it('works', () => {
        jest.spyOn(lib, 'getValue').mockImplementation( () => 'new value');
        expect(lib.callGetValue()).toBe('new value'); // it's not!
    });
// ...
```

I want to mock `getValue()` and make it return `'new value'`. It's not. Why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is unfortunately not really possible, see discussion in https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936